# asp.net Core 2 Razor Pages problem loading partial inside conditional

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I created a partial page view that is a box that for displaying form validation errors:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto align-self-center">
        <i class="fas fa-times-circle fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
</div>
```

From the main page view, I want to load this partial page view only if any validation errors exist:

```
@if (ViewData.ModelState.ErrorCount > 0)
{
    <partial name="Partial/_ValidationErrorSummary"/>
}
```

When I first load the page the error summary does not display, which is what I want. But when I try to submit the form on the page nothing happens. If I remove the conditional `@if (ViewData.ModelState.ErrorCount > 0)` from the main page view, I am able to submit the form as expected. What am I doing wrong?

**Full Page HTML**

```
@page
@model RegisterModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Sign Up";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
            @if (ViewData.ModelState.ErrorCount > 0)
            {
                <partial name="Partial/_ValidationErrorSummary" />
            }
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Email">Email</label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Password">Password</label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Password" type="password"class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" type="password" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please show the html markup to help reproduce ?

Comment: Added Html markup

Answer (score 0):

Still not reproduce , but provide a code sample which meets your requirement , you can check that with your codes :

1. Create a Razor page template asp.net core application .
2. Create `Partial` folder inside `Pages` folder and add `_ValidationErrorSummary.cshtml`, use your codes .
3. Create a Razor page and use view model :

   ```
   public class RegisterModel : PageModel
   {
       [BindProperty]
       public Input Input { get; set; }

       public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
       public void OnGet()
       {
           ReturnUrl = "Create";
       }

       public IActionResult OnPost()
       {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               // do something
               return RedirectToPage("Contact");
           }
           else
           {
               return Page();
           }
       }
   }

   public class Input
   {

       [Required]
       public string Email { get; set; }

       [Required]
       public string Password { get; set; }

       [Required]
       public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. Put your html in page's html .

The above codes works as expected , if any other concern please feel free to let me know .